# GZIP encoded packet

Tags: http, networking, compression, gzip

I am trying to analyse and decompress a gzip compressed packet over http connection.

**This is the header:**

POST /api/myapi/myapp HTTP/1.1

user-agent: Dart/2.10 (dart:io)

content-type: application/json;

charset=utf-8

accept-encoding: gzip

content-length: 194

host: api.myapi.com

**Data:**

"nQKagsQrbtlG4FUE+gZ2DCg0xhv0jFjx4YRyhj6rWTeGp9CyxKVY6psWlA/w/VEqcnVcOdw1YGBNLKAjPLr6ZLDYRoId3M/rJI0Uva5MD13OO0J22t3bt3nH8g+euURPwTofmxzZT4pKb36S9pIPJLe4BY0CM5CgK06kIbPA1RpIk2ce2U3q0pShPD3NP4qz"

As I [read](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) , GZIP compressed message should have magic of: *1f 8b*, which is not appearing in this case .

Am I missing something ?
Is it even GZIP compressed ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [“What topics can I ask about here?”](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [“What types of questions should I avoid asking?”](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read (the Stack Overflow question checklist)[http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922]. You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is not a gzip stream, either as is, or decoded from Base64.